# Fastest method implementing number multiplication in strings (1000000 digits)

Tags: algorithm

I want to write fastest possible algorithm for 2 number multiplications.
Each number has max digits around 1000000 and is contained in string.

Anyone want to tell about this problem? I searching really speed solution.

Comment: If you want the result in a string then won't you will need up to 1TB of storage to hold the answer?

Comment: @philcolbourn The product will only have 2 million digits ;).

Comment: @Paul When you multiply numbers with A and B digits the product will have A+B digits, not A*B digits. For example multiplying 1e10 * 1e10 = 1e20, not 1e100.

Comment: @Bus: my bad - you're right - I answered this too early in the morning. `;-)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should convert your string to a binary representation of the number. After that, one of the fastest multiplication algorithms I know of is [Karatsuba's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm).

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article Strassen's algorithm should outperform Karatsuba's starting at numbers 10k to 40k digits long.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Pablo's answer, suppose each number is a string 1000008 decimal digits long. You could convert that to be 111112 9-digit decimal numbers, each stored in a UInt32. Do your multiplication algorithm on those. (Note you will have to use UInt64 to hold the result of multiplying two UInt32 sections, so you may want a 64-bit machine.) That should give you a factor of 9^2 or 9^log2(3) speedup over base 10, depending on the algorithm.